# Is the implementation of this Z-transform correct?

Tags: z-transform

I am reviewing the simulation of a control system. One of the system's requirement diagrams currently contains the following:
[image]

N-DOT is the shaft acceleration, DT is the update rate in milliseconds. This is how the above was implemented years ago, based on an earlier revision of the requirement document that is no longer available, and may have been different from the current one:

`ndot = 0.052 / DT * ( shaft_speed - shaft_speed_pv ) + 0.91  * ndot`

where `shaft_speed_pv` is the previous value of `shaft_speed`.

**Question**: is the above implementation correct? My understanding of Z-transforms is somewhat basic. I get that $1 - Z^{-1}$ represents the increment of the input signal over the last pass, but the denominator escapes me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct:

With $\mathcal{Z}$ denoting a z-transform and
\begin{align}
&X(z) = \mathcal{Z}\{\text{SHAFT SPEED}\}\\
&Y(z) = \mathcal{Z}\{\text{N-DOT}\} 
\end{align}
the z-transforms, respectively, of $\text{SHAFT_SPEED}$ and $\text{N-DOT}$, your transfer function looks like:
$$\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{0.052}{\text{DT}}\frac{1-z^{-1}}{1-0.91z^{-1}}$$
\begin{align}
&\Leftrightarrow \text{DT}\,\left(Y(z) - 0.91Y(z)z^{-1}\right) = 0.052\, (X(z)  - X(z)z^{-1})\\
&\Leftrightarrow Y(z) = \cfrac{0.052}{\text{DT}}\,(X(z)  - X(z)z^{-1}) + 0.91Y(z)z^{-1}
\end{align}
which in the time domain gives:
$$y[n] = \frac{0.052}{\text{DT}}\left(x[n] - x[n-1]\right) + 0.91y[n-1]$$
or, in code:

```
ndot = 0.052 / DT * ( shaft_speed - shaft_speed_pv ) + 0.91 * ndot
```